# What is the best way to convert VGA to digital feed efficiently?

Tags: live-recording, mixing

I'm looking for a solution that I can get a feed from video projectors' VGA output to a media station (at this moment it is a mac) where I'm capturing camera feed and presentation from the speaker.

As a given prosumer equipments, I'm having a hdmi feed into Blackmagic mini recorder to thunberbolt output. The projector has only outputs to VGA and that is where I'm having the challenge.

My another thought is to have hdmi cable that is long enough from the stage to the media station and using secondary Blackmagic mini recorder to output to Thunderbolt.

Any suggestion other than this?

Comment: How far is it from the projector to the Mac?

Comment: projector to the mac would be in 10-20 feet. Stage to the mac would be around 100-150feet.

Comment: Related for the longer run - https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2873/whats-the-best-setup-to-transfer-a-digital-or-analog-video-over-100-ft/

Comment: VGA related - https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10827/record-dvi-signal-sxga

Comment: Also VGA related - https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9118/help-with-the-epiphan-vga2usb-frame-grabber/

Comment: Your description of the situation isn't particularly clear.  What are the available outputs at the stage?  If you can get a digital feed, that's preferable to going analog.  How would the projector work if you were using an HDMI out at the stage?

Comment: @AJHenderson, I'm assuming that laptop at the stage would have 2 outputs, 1 vga/dvi + 1 hdmi. So the projector would get the feed from the vga/dvi. I was just curious to know if there is a better way to run from the projector without going to have 2 separate cables.

Comment: if above situation with atleast 1 hdmi output at the stage fails I would have the option of having ability to convert from projector vga output. Thanks for your help